# NestJS-Mongoose: cannot access fullDocument on ChangeEvent<any>

Tags: typescript, mongoose, model, nestjs, watch

I have the following basic snippet of code and my aim is to get the fullDocument property from the `obj: ChangeEvent` however I am not able to access this property (`Property 'fullDocument' does not exist on type 'ChangeEvent<any>'`). The only properties I can access are _id, clusterTime and operationType. Is there something I am missing or should I just query the fullDocument non-directly (`obj['fullDocument']`)?

```
const changeStream = this.model.watch([], { fullDocument: 'updateLookup' })
      .on('change', obj => {
        console.log(obj.fullDocument);
      });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you're having (TypeScript complaining about the missing property) is due to **unspecialized** return type generic [`mongodb.ChangeStream`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/96bddc7af68f2421c9284e98aebb18037d898e9e/types/mongodb/index.d.ts#L4909-L4919) in mongoose's `Model.watch` method (in both [`@types/mongoose`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/96bddc7af68f2421c9284e98aebb18037d898e9e/types/mongoose/index.d.ts#L3362-L3371) and official [`mongoose`](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/ffb811f0c1efafb127d45bdd546d9d7ce6979dc6/index.d.ts#L792-L793) types, I'm assuming you are using mongoose 5.x branch).

For example `@types/mongodb` package declares/specializes the return type on the [`watch`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/96bddc7af68f2421c9284e98aebb18037d898e9e/types/mongodb/index.d.ts#L2547-L2559) method correctly.

The real solution would be to create a Pull Request fixing the return type of the `watch` return type in the aforementioned package repositories, and/or report the issue to maintainers. For a quick 'fix' you could resort to type casting like this (for the cleanest `changeStream` shape the `MySchema` should be the class you've annotated with `@Schema`):

```js
const changeStream = this.model
  .watch([], { fullDocument: 'updateLookup' }) as ChangeStream<MySchema>; // <-- specialize using the cast
      
changeStream.on('change', obj => {
  console.log(obj.fullDocument);
});
```

Also be aware that [MongoDB Change Stream](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/) requires Replica Set or Sharded Cluster.

Comment: I do not use Mongoose.  As far as I can tell this is an issue with the underlying mongodb nodejs driver.  Even if you provide a type parameter to `watch`, the `change` event will still provide a `fullDocument` with the broad `Document` type.